# How to get URL while navigating to other site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am developing a test where I need to validate the URL while its navigating to the retailer's site

For instance, when I click the Product, it navigates to retailer's page. I need to capture the URL when it is navigating to the retailer's page but it should not be of the previous page & even not of the retailer's page.

Is there any method in Ruby or Capybara to get that URL? I have tried to implement this method but it's not giving the correct URL.

```
url = URI.parse(current_url)
def validate_url(url)
  browser= Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
  puts "current URL = #{browser.current_url}" if @verbose
  assert_includes browser.current_url, url
end
#Actual Output url =http://www.shopstyleqa.com/browse/womens-clothes
#Expected Output url=http://www.shopstyleqa.com/action/loadRetailerProductPage
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Capybara is designed to emulate a users use of a browser it doesn't report on redirects so there is no way to get the intermediate url if the browser is being redirected to a different one.  You could verify the original URL that is going to be requested if it's in a links href attribute or a data attribute on whatever element represents the project, etc.

On a side note comparing current_url with eq or includes is a recipe for flaky tests.  Instead you should use the [assert_current_path](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capybara/Capybara/SessionMatchers#assert_current_path-instance_method) assertion which uses Capybaras waiting/retrying behavior - In your case it would be something like

```
assert_current_path("http://www.expected.com/expected_url", url: true)
```